# I rm -rf'd /var/!

Tags: filesystem, files

I recently rm -rf'd all of /var/ on my box and I've made a VM with the same OS/bit, I plan to upload all of the contents from the fresh VM and replace my messed up /var/ on my box with it. What's a fast way to do this? I currently have the VM open and FTP is enabled for my box, but is there another way? Because something is messed with my graphical interface too, I can't see any new short-cuts I create.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a backup ;)
You can use tar to pack var on your new system copy it to the old one and extract it there. Before you do that you should install the same software you had on the old system to the new one, because your package database also resides in var. You can do this as a workaround but should really consider doing a fresh install soon (and backups;)